# Where is libmtp?

Tags: 14.10, mtp

I'm trying to install playedit-0.1.6 (an editor for Android playlists) in Kubuntu 14.10. It's only available in source form, it seems.  So I went through the **configure** ritual several times, each time having to install another batch of software.  But eventually I got stuck: the configurator required libmtp, and **apt-get install** couldn't find it.  So where is it? If it doesn't exist, is there another way to install playedit?

Comment: Did you try [libmtp-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libmtp-dev)?

Comment: This might be related to the fact that (K)Ubuntu 14.10 is not supported abymore. It might be a good idea to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install:

```
libmtp-runtime
libmtp-common
libmtp9
```

The latter contains `libmtp.so`, two other may be dependencies

From my system:

```
$ dpkg -l *libmtp*
==================
ii  libmtp-common                     1.1.6-20-g1b9f164-1ub all                   Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) common files
ii  libmtp-runtime                    1.1.6-20-g1b9f164-1ub amd64                 Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) runtime tools
un  libmtp8                           <нет>                 <нет>                 (описание недоступно)
ii  libmtp9:amd64                     1.1.6-20-g1b9f164-1ub amd64                 Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) library
```

Comment: I got one step further but now it needs libmpg123.  I do have libmpg123-0:i386 installed, but I don't know what to do to get the playedit configurator to use it.

Comment: Surely, you joking?

`$ dpkg -l *libmpg123*` gave me two packages to install: `libmpg123-0:amd64` and `libmpg123-0:i386`. You should just `apt-get install libmpg123` and let your system decide which architecture to install.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PPA or you can even compile the program yourself if you really want to..

**PPA** (precise, quantal, raring, saucy, trusty, utopic)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:glennric/mtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playedit
```

**Compile**

At first use this command:

```
./autogen.sh
```

If messages appear like this:

```
`No package 'libmpg123' found`
```

install the missing package with this command, eg.:

```
sudo apt-get install libmpg123-dev
```

Then run:

```
make
```

and install with `make install`:

```
sudo make install
```

or with `checkinstall` for a deb package

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: I did install libmtp-dev.   The problems with libmpg showed up after I installed it and again did a configure.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libmtp9`